# How to improve resume without job experience?

Tags: resume, career-development, certification

Recently I finished my degree in statistics at a renowned university in my country. However, I'm having some difficulty getting a first job due to lack of experience.

Now I'm doing some online courses about machine learning and python, while looking for a job. Is it bad to put these online courses in the curriculum? Should I describe the topics of the course?

I have not had direct contact with these themes presented in these courses and they have value in the market, besides being of an area of ​​my interest.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE. Use '[Combination Style](https://www.thebalance.com/resume-examples-listed-by-style-2063167)' so they don't realize you're hiding 'Functional Style' and place the online courses and hobby separately where work experience would go.

This gives the appearance of a lower experienced person, after second glance, while emphasizing the fine school you attended. If you *are* exactly what they're looking for they will call ...

Getting a start somewhere is the key both to your first job and your second one. If the first place is good there's no reason not to stay but if it's not so great you'll have experience with which to jump ship with.

As long as the first place isn't actually *bad* don't worry too much, get a start somewhere. I still remember calling a large and well known company and the lady at HR telling me "We are not hiring, we get a lot of resumes; too many. If you have three or more Doctorates we would keep your resume on file, otherwise we would have to toss it out. In any event I encourage you **not** to send a resume."

Not what I was expecting but at least she seemed genuine. - So don't set your sights too high. I went to the best school too, sometimes people realize the importance of that and sometimes they don't; don't be discouraged or waste your time dwelling at a few select businesses, just keep moving forward.

I noticed that you're not joined to [stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11021/resume-buzz-words), you might keep current on what's up in your area of expertise over there and obtain more information specific to your interest.